# Sidecap package SCFigure centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, sidecap

I have some problems with the sidecap package. The figure and the caption are always centered. What i want is that the figure starts at the beginning of the frame and that the caption should go until the end of the frame.

I already tried making the captionwidth larger but when i do that the caption will start in the figure. Does anybody knows the solution?

```
\begin{SCfigure}[][h]
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{RogowskiStroom}
    \captionsetup{width=1.2\textwidth}
    \caption[Opstelling van een Rogowski spoel bij een geleider.]{\textbf{Opstelling van een Rogowski spoel bij een geleider.} Overgenomen uit\cite{Rogowski}.}
    \label{fig_rogowski}
\end{SCfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you mean is not clear. What is this frame you mention? The right margin?

Comment: Oops, indeed with the frame i mean the max text width. What i want is that the caption starts a new line at the end of text width.

Comment: Yes, I supposed you used `showframe`…

Comment: True, that confused me. But to be clear,

I want to have the figure from the beginning instead of an offset. Same for the caption, it stops before the max text width has reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use a big optional argument (it's the ratio between the caption width and the figure width).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{sidecap, caption}

\begin{document}

\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}
\begin{SCfigure}[50][h]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{TasmanianDevil}
\caption[Opstelling van een Rogowski spoel bij een geleider.]{\textbf{Opstelling van een Rogowski spoel bij een geleider.} Overgenomen uit\cite{Rogowski}.}
\label{fig_rogowski}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, that is probably the only thing that i didn't tried from the sidecap package options. Thanks for helping!